# Gradle java 9+ conflict in resource folder name

Tags: java, gradle, java-module

I have library using JavaFX, which has resource folder "fxml". Built by gradle using java 9+ as lib.jar, I include it into my other project, which is built in the same way.

Unfortunately there si following issue:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package fxml in both module A (my current project I am trying to build) and module B (lib.jar)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-12/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

It is really complaining about the "fxml" folder in resources, because when I rename the folder, this issue is gone.

I would like to ask how to resolve this conflict using gradle, I found a lot of articles about how to resolve dependencies but none about folder names.

Comment: *when I rename the folder, this issue is gone.*, does that not work as a resolution?

Comment: In a way yes, but I would like to know proper way or resolution. Imagine your project has 20 libs, there is pretty high chance some resource folder names would collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource folders and Java packages are essentially the same. The problem is that with your project you add additional resources to a package that is already present in the JDK. That is prohibited.

Basically rename your resources folder/package and you're done.

Comment: So in a way fxml is reserved name (package) as long as I use JavaFX. Do I understand it right ? And if I rename both lib and main project "fxml" as for example "fxmlc" they wont collide anymore.

Comment: Yes. Typically package names somehow include some kind of origin. E.g. `org.springframework` or `com.oracle`. But `fxmlc` will do the trick.

Comment: I can confirm that renaming the folder to fxml-layouts in both projects resolved the conflict. Thank you

Comment: I don’t think `fxml` is reserved, but it looks you are trying to use two different modules with it (the library and your project) and that is not possible. As mentioned package names have to be unique.

Comment: @JoséPereda I didn't mean to say that `fxml` is reserved. I'm not very much into the modular JDK thing, so your wording is perhaps better...

Comment: @dpr I was referring to one of the comments, your answer is fine, but yes, it applies not only to the existing modules in the JDK but also to any third party module added to the module path.

Comment: @JoséPereda but renaming the folder in both main project and the library to the same name resolves the conflict.

Comment: Indeed, because both are in the same module, and actually there is no distinction between then as explained in the answer.

Comment: @dpr So you want to say that in java should resource folders be under the same structure like the java classes, containing domain names ?

Comment: @LukasHanacek Yes. By using the domain-style pattern, it is ensured that no 2 modules will be using the same package names. Same holds for resource folders. You could for example use `hanacek.fxml`. This would minimize the chance of name clashes such as the above.